# Typing Text in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Guys i want to make my typing text in to Two lines.

Here is my **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jc52k/)**

Plz check this code

**HTML**

```
  <div id="container">

    <div class="writer">Hi! This is a test text. 
        <br><br>
        Can any one         
        Help me in this ?.</div>  

</div>
```

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
var txt = $('.writer').text();
var timeOut;
var txtLen = txt.length;
var char = 0;
$('.writer').text('|');
(function typeIt() {   
    var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        $('.writer').text(type + '|');
        typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            $('.writer').text($('.writer').text().slice(0, -1)); // remove the '|'
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, humanize);
}());
```

Comment: I'm loving it! Nice work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add [`white-space: pre-line;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) declaration to the `.writer` in order to break the lines, as follows:

```css
.writer {
    font:bold 23px arial;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/jc52k/1/)**

> **[16.6 White space: the 'white-space' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop)**
>
> `pre-line` This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space. Lines
>   are broken at preserved newline characters, and as necessary to fill
>   line boxes.

It's worth noting that `pre-line` value [is supported in **IE8+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Browser_compatibility).