# Imitating "typing text" with jQuery inside of a textbox when the text is too long

Tags: jquery, text, input, textbox, typing

I'm trying to create an animation for typing text with jQuery and I have a problem, when the text is too long I can see the all the typed text. When a real person is typing, the txtbox keeps visible  the last part of the text (I cant reproduce that effect). Here is an example with the text `This an example with a very long text`. **A** is how I expect it to look when it finish, **B** is how it really looks.

[image: Example]

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jc52k/2/)**

Hope you can help.

---

P.D.: I have checked other topics but even when they are great, I'm looking for something more simple. Here they are:

[Typing Text in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554589/typing-text-in-jquery)

[Typing text animation using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760391/typing-text-animation-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the solution for responsive design based on [dantella's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241812/imitating-typing-text-with-jquery-inside-of-a-textbox-when-the-text-is-too-lon/35241944#35241944). Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jc52k/4/).

**HTML**

```
<input id="input1" type="text" data-text="This is an example with a very long text" value="" style="width:200px;" />
<input id="input2" type="text" data-text="This is an example with a very long text" value="" style="width:150px;" />
<input id="input3" type="text" data-text="This is an example with a very long text" value="" style="width:100px;" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var func_showText = function (target, message, index, interval, pixelsPerLetter) {   
    if (index < message.length) {
    var maxLetters =  Math.round($(target).width()/ pixelsPerLetter);
    var str=$(target).val();
    if($(target).val().length > maxLetters){
        str=str.substring(str.length-maxLetters, str.length);
    }
        $(target).val(str+message[index++]);
        setTimeout(function () { func_showText(target, message, index, interval, pixelsPerLetter); }, interval);
    }
}

func_showText('#input1', $('#input1').attr('data-text'),0,200, 7.5);
func_showText('#input2', $('#input2').attr('data-text'),0,200, 7.5);
func_showText('#input3', $('#input3').attr('data-text'),0,200, 7.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you decide how many characters you want to display you can do a substring function from the end less this value till the end
in javascript it could be like this:

```
var view_characters=30;
var str = "This an example wit h a very long text";
var res = str.substring(str.length-view_characters, str.length);
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var view_characters=30;
    var str = "This an example wit h a very long text";
    var res = str.substring(str.length-view_characters, str.length);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to extract characters from the string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, it looks like an option (I'm not sure it is going to look the same way in all browser, but it could be). I need send a form with the example text after that and this way the text is truncated, but I can do something (a little tricky) to solve it. **EDIT:** Now, I remember my website is responsive and it is not going to work.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I can work even if I have a responsive design. I created and answer, so check it out.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me good.
I set `var pixelsPerLetter=5.5` and it works.

Be carefull that this solution may not work if you apply different font sizes to input fields (in above example it was using `font-size=12px`)
I've tested successfully on IE11, Google Chrome and Firefox on Windows 8.

Comment: Good, thanx for testing it on different browser. If the `font-size` just need to adjust `pixelsPerLetter`, bigger `font-size` requires more `pixelsPerLetter`